# Script de consulta para sumar costos dentro de un rango de fechas sql

Tags: date, sql, busqueda, sum

Tengo una tabla que contiene ordenes de servicio de unidades, que tienen una fecha de inicio y una fecha cierre.

Necesito saber cuales son las ordenes que están entre los lapsos de la fecha de inicio y el de cierre, y acumular el monto generado es decir en lugar de mostrarme todas las ordenes que existen solo estas.

> Por ejemplo: la orden 39097 y 38855 van juntas ya que la orden 38855 inicia antes de la fecha de cierre de la 39097
> 40760 y 40362 van juntas ya que la orden 40362 inicia antes de la fecha de cierre de la 40760

```
A-02    39097   2012-06-20 12:47:00.000 2012-07-12 11:52:00.000
A-02    38855   2012-06-29 10:02:00.000 2012-07-02 16:30:29.593

A-02    40760   2012-08-01 12:19:00.000 2012-09-03 11:22:35.597
A-02    40362   2012-08-10 10:12:00.000 2012-08-20 12:17:00.000

select id_unidad,id_orden,fecha_inicio,fecha_cierre
from mtto_orden
order by id_unidad,fecha_inicio
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a StackOverflow en español. Para que tu pregunta tenga mejor probabilidad de ser respondida, considera [editarla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/381894/edit) para incluir la descripción de la tabla, una muestra de datos y el resultado esperado.

Comment: Hola. No está muy clara la pregunta. Puntualmente, esto: 

" y acumular el monto generado es decir en lugar de mostrarme todas las ordenes que existen solo estas por ejemplo la orden

39097 y 38855 van juntas ya que la orden 38855 inicia antes de la fecha de cierre de la 39097 40760 y 40362 van juntas ya que la orden 40362 inicia antes de la fecha de cierre de la 40760"

¿Vos necesitás agrupar de a 2? ¿Que es lo que necesitás acumular?

Comment: Hola no, necesito acumular todos los registros que existan entre esas fechas, solo puse dos ejemplos pero entre esas fecha de cierre, puede haber mas registros con fecha de inicio, necesito acumular los costos, también hay una columna de costos